# How can I get the unique row from the value of 2 coloumn?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a table named `"info"` and the columns `id,userid,groupid`. Now I want to fetch all data from the table but if `userid` and `groupid` have duplicate value I want them one time even if

`userid = 5` and group `id = 1`
 or
 `userid=1` and `groupid=5`

Then I want 1 row from this.

Comment: What about the `id` column?  In your example, would the two records 1/5 and 5/1 have the same `id` value or a different one?

Comment: do you want this solution by sql or php?  If you want this solution by sql then you can use distinct.

Comment: And userid = 5 and group id = 1 or userid=1 and groupid=5 is not a duplicate if userid = 5 and group id = 1 or userid=5 and groupid=1 then you can treat them as a duplicate by the way I don't know what you want to do I think you thinking different.

Answer (score 0):

You may use a least/greatest trick here:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    LEAST(userid, groupid) AS userid,
    GREATEST(userid, groupid) AS groupid
FROM info;
```

Note that I have left the `id` column out from the select, on the grounds that perhaps the two records have different values.  In this case, it is not clear *which* of the two `id` values you would want.

Comment: Tim Biegeleisen sir, I have more column and I want to select all but I want the unique from user id and group id. even both have same value as difderent place.

Comment: This requirement makes no sense/is not well defined.  _Which_ value from each of the records do you want to keep, for each column?  Can you show us some actual data?

Comment: sorry sir,I can give you another example. suppose table for message name message where column touid for which one I'm sending messege and byuid for who sending message. from this table I want to get the data with wich one I chat with.  now if user A send message to B there is a new row where byuid = A and touid = B and again if B send message to A there will be a new row where byuid = B and touid= A now if the send 10 msg each other there will 20 row where touid = A and byuid= B is 10, and touid=B and byuid=A is 10. from this table when I use mysqli query I want 1 result only.

Comment: You're not ready to ask a question here IMO, because you lack to ability to articular your question to us.  You need to be able to show us data describing your problem; this is critical for SQL questions.  If you _can't_ do this, it means you haven't thought about the problem enough.

Comment: I am really sorry sir for my weekness. here I upload  a photo from this table from the red marked I want 1 row and from the blue mark I want 1 row.  https://i.stack.imgur.com/lFjoM.png

Comment: You still haven't said which values for the `id` and `text`.  Do you understand that the pairs of records may have different values?